# Inserting values to msql from php

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm writing a php code to insert the personal information of a customer in a one table named "bookings" and his booked seats in another table named"bookseat" in the same database,same php file.When the code executes,the personal information is stored in the relevant table,but the booked seats are not stored.When I insert a value manually to the bookseat table,I see that though the previous values from the php file are not saved,there have been some saved records which are not shown(Because the Auto-Incremented column(sid) in the table seemed to have incremented).

[image: Here is a screenshot of the bookseat table.]

And here is my php code.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "titan3d";

$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$nic = $_SESSION['nic'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$teleno = $_SESSION['teleno'];
$sdate = $_SESSION['sdate'];
$stime = $_SESSION['stime'];
$now = $_SESSION['now'];

$bookseat = array(11, 18, 12);
$arrlength = count($bookseat);

if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
    }
if(isset($_POST['nic']))
    {
        $nic = $_POST["nic"];
    }
if(isset($_POST['email']))
    {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    }
if(isset($_POST['teleno']))
    {
        $teleno = $_POST["teleno"];
    }
if(isset($_POST['sdate']))
    {
        $sdate = $_POST["sdate"];
    }
if(isset($_POST['stime']))
    {
        $stime = $_POST["stime"];
    }
if(isset($_POST['now']))
    {
        $now = $_POST["now"];
    }

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);  
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO bookings (name, nic, email, teleno, sdate, stime)
VALUES ('$name', '$nic', '$email', '$teleno', '$sdate', '$stime')";

for($i = 0; $i < count($bookseat); ++$i){
    $SQL_project_has_type = "INSERT INTO bookseat (seat, bid)
         VALUES({$bookseat[$i]}, $now)";
    mysqli_query($conn, $SQL_project_has_type);
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header('Location: http://localhost/My%20Project/booksuccess.html');
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Is there something wrong here?Can somebody sort this out for me?

Comment: probably has something to do with your using 2 tables and a probable foreign key.  Which table is the screenshot associated with? Do you have a TRIGGER or EVENT happening also?

Comment: I think you need `mysqli_insert_id()` value instead of the value of `$now` in your bookseat INSERT string..

Comment: It's the book seat table where the booked seats are stored.The other table works fine.(No triggers or events.)

Comment: I've used $ now to get the current auto increment value in the other table,so that I can save many seats for 1 person.

Comment: The current auto increment is changed after you do INSERT on bookings. You can retrieve the real current auto increment using `mysqli_insert_id()` - which relates both inserts.

Comment: I missed it, you executed the second SQL string first. I think you have to execute first SQL first before doing the insert on bookseats.

Comment: But here,I ve got the current auto increment value before the insertion and saved it in a variable.So it does not change,right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170215/discussion-between-mr-blue-and-ajitha-malkanthi).

Comment: Can you give me a more clear explanation on how to to it?

Comment: Check if some error is occurring while the DB is updated, just in case. A_I marked fields will get updated in that case but not the other columns. I faced it once so suggesting it.